# How to Set A Cookie Expiration Date To Another Cookie Value

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

As you know we can read the name and value of a cookie, but we cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time. This is because when the browser sends cookie information to the server, it does not include the expiration information.
One solution to get the expiry date is to set the cookie's expiration date to another cookie which  can be read later to get the expiration date of first cookie.

Using JavaScript, I have create the first cookie like this

```
let username = 'geoca';
function setCookie(cName, cValue, expDays) {
        let date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
}
setCookie('webexia', username, 30);
```

now can you please let me know how can I get and set the expiry of `webexia` cookie (the first cookie) to `getexpirey` cookie in JavaScript or in PHP?

```
setCookie('getexpirey', ?????, 30);
```

Comment: You can't get the expiration time from JavaScript, either. You'll need to calculate it yourself.

Comment: Use `now = new Date()` to get the current time, then `now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30)` to get the expiration time.